# Há algum problema em usar pygame.image.load() várias vezes?

Tags: pygame

Eu estou criando uma classe chamada `Button`, e uma das propriedades dessa classe é uma imagem.

Eu queria saber se tem problema, se dentro dessa classe eu usasse `self.imagem = pygame.image.load()` pra não precisar passar a imagem como argumento, já que nessa aplicação eu só vou ter uma imagem de botão.

Desse modo sempre que eu criar um Botão ele vai ler a mesma imagem de novo ou vai saber que ja carregou essa imagem antes e vai simplesmente puxar ela de um cache, sei lá?

Comment: elabore mais sua pergunta, talvez colocando um pedaço de código poderá ajudar mais a comunidade e te dar uma resposta mais precisa

Answer (score 1):

Sim - há um problema.

Ao contrário do sistema de importação de módulos do Python, que usa uma mecânica bem complicada para ler um arquivo do disco uma só vez, não importa quantas vezes você faça `import`, o pygame.image.load não incorpora nenhuma lógica do tipo: ele vai ler o arquivo do disco e descomprimi-lo cada vez que for executado.

Você pode ter uma função de inicialização que lê todas as suas imagens no início da execução do programa (ou todas as imagens da cena atual, no caso de um projeto grande), e guarde-as num dicionário. Daí você recupera as imagens do dicionário, em vez de usar o load toda vez.

Comment: Esse último parágrafo todo se aplica não só ao pygame e _engines_ de jogo, mas qualquer aplicação que seja um tanto quanto intensiva em imagens e não se deseja ter "soluços" de desempenho